# How to share context between two code blocks work using sessions?

Tags: org-mode, session

Based on the examples I've found on `:session` , I expect the following code blocks to share the same environment:

```
#+begin_src crystal :session foobar :results output
# some boilerplate:
def echo(word)
  puts word
  puts word
  puts word
end
#+end_src

#+begin_src crystal :session foobar :results output
# caller site:
echo("hey")
#+end_src
```

When I run these blocks I'm getting `undefined method 'echo' for top-level` error which essentially means the `echo` function is not defined on the second code block. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does `crystal` support separate compilation? If so, you may be able to use header args to link in the first object file to the second. ISTR that this can be done for `C` or `C++` but the details are hazy in my mind so you'll have to do some research.

Comment: AFAIK it does not support separate compilation. Based on the accepted answer, using `session` is off the table. I think I will post a separate question about doing this another way.

Comment: If crystal has a REPL (play mode? eval mode?) you could possibly do what you want through `bash` source blocks calling the REPL.

Comment: @mankoff There's an interpreter in the works but there's an eval mode. The issue with `bash` blocks I think would be losing the syntax highlighting (both in the editor and exports) similar to `noweb`. Maybe I can fork `ob-crystal` to support an `eval` mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:session` argument only applies to languages that support interactive sessions. `orgmode` cannot create an interactive session for compiled languages, and I think crystal is a compiled language.

I assume you're using https://github.com/brantou/ob-crystal. The relevant code in that package is:

```lisp
(defun org-babel-prep-session:crystal (_session _params)
  "This function does nothing as crystal is a compiled language with no
support for sessions"
  (error "Crystal is a compiled language -- no support for sessions"))
```

Comment: I wonder why the OP does not see the above error but (IIUC) a runtime error from `crystal` instead: maybe they are using an older (or a completely different) version of `ob-crystal`?

Comment: @NickD I wondered that too

Comment: @NickD, I was curious about that too. It either displays errors from `crystal` or stays silent if there were no runtime errors. It does not display the error message that's from the snippet in the answer. I'm using the latest version of `ob-crystal` from MELPA.

Comment: Well, AFAICT neither `org-babel-prep-session:crystal`, nor ``org-babel-load-session:crystal` is ever called (at least, `edebug` doesn't stop after I instrumented those two). I don't know yet whether that's a bug in `ob-core` or in `ob-crystal`. I suspect the latter but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Those two functions are not called by anybody: `org-babel-execute:crystal` (at least - maybe others?) needs to actually try (and fail) to initiate a session. Maybe you can open an issue with `ob-crystal` (or I will - but that will take an unknown length of time).